# (netbeans) jsf page not auto changing in browser

Tags: maven, jsf, netbeans, primefaces, jsf-2.2

i have weird issue when building jsf application in netbeans.
when i run index.xhtml and then i change some text inside that file and save,the file won't get update on the browser. the browser still have the old page. i also try to clean and build again (without shutting down tomcat) and the result still not updated. but when i stop tomcat and run the application again,the update will show.
i build it with maven project structure.
i use Netbeans 7.4, primefaces 4.0,JSF 2.2.5
i already tried to clear the browser cache and history,also give permission to the target folder in my project but it still can't update the view.

anybody have any experiece like this?do u have any solution?
thanks

Comment: in eclipse I have the same problem. it only refreshes if I clean the web app (forcing a new deployment) and restarting tomcat. I am afraid tomcat does not have hot deploy for jsf, as jboss has

Comment: but you can also try to set development = true like stated here http://tomee.apache.org/tomee-and-eclipse.html

Comment: usually i use tomcat for development app server. and everything works fine.the problem started after i try to load the project in intellij idea.when i load in netbeans again,the problem show

Comment: fancy bug huh? :-( looks like your IDEs are messing with you. sorry, I'm working with eclipse for decades, I know nothing about intellij and netbeans