# JSF page not being deployed after changing it

Tags: java, jsf, netbeans, glassfish, html

I was coding a JSF application with NetBeans 8.0 (patch 1.1) and GlassFish 4 when I noticed a problem. When I change my `index.xhtml` page and save it, normally, NetBeans automatically deploys the new version of the page and I can view the new version right away. Unfortunately, it seems not to be doing that in some very specific situations. Let me give you more details.

Here is my `index.xhtml`:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>Index</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <h:outputLabel for="inputValue" value="Input Value: "/>
            <br/>
            <h:inputText id="inputValue" value="#{someManagedBean.mainInput}" />
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Here is my ManagedBean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "someManagedBean")
@SessionScoped
public class SomeManagedBean implements Serializable {

    private String mainInput;

    public SomeManagedBean() {
    }

    public String getMainInput() {
        return mainInput;
    }

    public void setMainInput(String mainInput) {
        this.mainInput = mainInput;
    }
}
```

Well, initially, it is alright. I run my application normally and the page is shown perfectly. However, if I change the `.xhtml` adding/removing/changing a button, text or anything, then save it and get back to the browser, sometimes the old version of the page is still there. Sometimes it works, but sometimes after some `change > save > reload browser > change > save > reload browser > change > save ...` the page just stops being updated.

At first I thought it could be the browser's cache, however, opening another browser and loading the page won't work as well. Clearing the cache or simply disabling it won't work too. The older version  of the page is still there. I need to wait like a minute or two for the page to be updated. Even clicking in `Run Project` in NetBeans won't work.

The only way to immediately update the page is to deploy the whole application again. Well, it works, but come on, it takes a lot of time just to update a single change to the page.

Anyone has ever noticed a problem like that? What you think it might be?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: There are some other people who are getting this problem too. Here are some links:

https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=218806 
[(netbeans) jsf page not auto changing in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21934483/netbeans-jsf-page-not-auto-changing-in-browser)

EDIT 2: Deleted my project and created another one. Different page, different context path, different everything. Still getting the bug.

EDIT 3: My project is in `Development`:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: Hi Giovani, could you solve this issue? On which environment are you running? I have the same issues on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Hey Tim. Unfortunately, I could not. I was running in OS X Mavericks. I just gave up after some time.

Comment: Hi Giovani, to me it seems to be working now. Problem was a build error that was kind of hidden. The Java files were still deployed so I had a inconsistent deployment. So after I did a mvn clean, I started the project again and now both, JSF and Java files are hotdeployed again.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I also ran into the same issue, the page would not be updated after saving it.

This was it for me:

Bug 218806 - jsf pages are not deployed on save
https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=218806

Updating to NetBeans 8 worked for me.

Regards.

EDIT: I just saw you are already on 8.

Comment: Are you on Patch 1.1 ?

Comment: Yes. I am. Any more thoughts?

Comment: I would start by determining if the problem is NetBeans or Glassfish.  If the files are not copied then I would manually set all the configuration to allow the hot swap, otherwise, Glassfish migh be caching the compiled page if your Project_Stage is production. Maybe start by making sure that this exists on the web.xml:

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>

Comment: I think the problem is with NetBeans. My project is in `Development`:

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>